# How do I input one character and one integer to get a triangle answer?

Tags: c#

so i came up with this but it only prints in a straight line not triangle, i want it to look like a triangle

this is my code

```
        string character;
        int width;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
        width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a character");
        character = Console.ReadLine();
         int size = width, i = size;
        while (Math.Abs(--i) < size)
            Console.WriteLine( character, size - Math.Abs(i));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the overload of `Console.WriteLine` that takes a format string.
It will not repeat `character`.

Instead, you can write `new String(char, n)` to repeat `char` `n` times.

Comment: I want the character the person enters to be the one it repeats, how do i do that?

Comment: @user: You need to get the first `char` value from the string, by writing `someString[0]`.